# How to tilt a product image taken from sideways in such a way that the front view of the product is visible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective

I have the following image:

[image]

I need to tilt the image such that the front of the product is visible as seen below:

[image]

I tried perspective warp in photoshop but was not able to accomplish this. I have 1000s of such images for which I want to do this. What is the fastest possible way to do this?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can't do that in Photoshop. It's not possible.  If it was modelled in a 3D program such as Blender, you could just rotate the object. Might be better to retake the photos instead.

Comment: If you have some extreme luck you can edit a missing detail or color to another photo which contains a geometrically equal object and is shot from the wanted direction. If a half of a symmetric object is fully visible one can warp the visible half to the right watching direction and make the other half by duplicating, flipping and cloning  off some minor seam inaccuracies. It's not easy to get it right. An example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyiSx.jpg I'm afraid this is quite far from what's expected.